# wanted few properties regarding UITextField

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

hello guys  i have taken a UITextfield in my application whose capacity is one(max length allowed is one). i implemented it as desired but when i click in the textField the cursor doesn't seems to be at centre(its looking towards top of the cell). i declared a property to set the text alignment to center for the textfield.is there any other property to be set?

my other requirement is the text entered by the user should be automatically converted to CAPITALS by default,i assigned the predefined property :

cellTextField.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;

but not working.can someone help me in both aspects if possible.

TNQ in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make text converted to capital, make the textField delegate as self and add the following code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {


    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *string = textField.text;

    string = [string uppercaseString];

    textField.text = string;



    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025593/ipad-uitextfield-cursor-not-centering-when-resizing-frame-with-contentvertical) to get information on why the is looking towards the top of the cell.

For all letters to be entered in upper case, I would suggest you to go through:

[UITextInputTraits protocol (adopted by UITextField)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

You could also go through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708775/uikeyboard-turn-caps-lock-on) for more details. I hope I answered your questions.